# After updating to Angular 14 karma pact test runner not closing after done

Tags: angular, karma-runner, pact

I have a command to run the pact tests:

```
"ng test --karma-config karma-pact.conf.js --main src/test-pact.ts --ts-config src/tsconfig-pact.spec.json --watch=false --source-map=false"
```

They are running, but after done with the tests it doesn't kill the process and just wait. This happens after updating from Angular 12 to Angular 14.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say why that's happening, but some extra debugging / logging would be helpful here (e.g. setting `logLevel` to  `DEBUG` would be a good start).

It should be noted that `pact-web` is now [deprecated](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/issues/626), and you should really consider moving to a Node based testing framework such as Jest or Mocha to get continued updates to your Pact tests.